# Bootstrap Popover Link Inside a Label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

On a form, I have a typical opt-in text checkbox but also have a link in that label. That link doesn't go anywhere but rather triggers a Bootstrap 3 Popover for additional detail.

It works, however clicking the popover link also unchecks the checkmark. Saw other questions on SO and solutions but they were for normal links and didn't apply to a javascript link link like this. Any thoughts?

The of course first thing one would think of is to have the link outside the label, but then the text won't wrap with the preceding text and will always have to appear beneath the disclaimer text which is not desired.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input class="optin" type="checkbox" checked value="">My disclaimer text here. <a type="button" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Title Here" data-content="Popover body text here">My Link</a>.
</label>
</div>
```

Assuming I need to integrate stop propagation somehow but can't seem to determine how to integrate in this scenario.

Comment: Firstly, I must ask why you have an `<a>` tag within the `<label>` tag?
Second, have you tried adding `onclick="event.preventDefault();"` to the `<a>` tag?

Comment: The details of the need I don't think will affect the solution on how to achieve it, if it is relevant let me know. Tried event.preventDefault based on another SO post, but caused issues with the popup opening/closing. The answer maybe along those lines.